# Vanilla JavaScript: Timed innerHTML not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

```
let text = ["Words", "Here"];

setInterval(() => {
    var currentItem = 0;

    if (!(currentItem > text.length)) {
        document.getElementById("scrollingText").innerHTML = text[currentItem];
        currentItem++;
        console.log("Updated to: " + currentItem);
    } else {
        currentItem = 0;
    }
}, 1000);
```

I'm creating a simple paragraph with the ID 'scrollingText' on the page which this JavaScript is meant to be updating every 1 second with the next item in the array list 'text', and if it exceeds the amount of elements inside the array list it will reset the counter.

I have got the script currently to update the scrollingText to the first item and it indicates in the browser console that it has done so, however after that it completely ignores the innerHTML code and just continues to increment currentItem, not even passing through the currentItem exceeds array length check.

Anybody have any ideas on why this is not functioning as intended?

Answer (score 5):

Your `currentItem` is not persistent; you're re-initializing it to `0` each time the function runs. Put it outside the function instead, so that there's only ever one binding to that variable.

But there's another problem: your `if (!(currentItem > text.length)) {` test will pass if `currentItem === text.length`, in which case `text[currentItem]` will be `undefined`. You might change to

```
if (currentItem < text.length)
```

But then, there will be 2 seconds of having the last item on the page (compared to 1 second of having every other item on the page). You might consider resetting `currentItem` to `0` in the same block that you assign to `scrollingText`.

Something else to keep in mind is that, unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup, it's better to assign to `textContent` than `innerHTML`. (`textContent` is quicker, safer, and more predictable):

```js
const text = ["Words", "Here"];
let currentItem = 0;
const scrollingText = document.getElementById("scrollingText");
setInterval(() => {
  scrollingText.textContent = text[currentItem];
  currentItem = (currentItem + 1) % text.length;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="scrollingText"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the condition, `currentItem` is re-setting to `0` in each call of `setInterval()`. Declare `currentItem` outside of `setInterval()`.

The current condition (`if`) is allowing you to iterate the `text` array more than it's length, which producing some unintentional output. You can correct and simplify that like the following:

```
if (currentItem < text.length)
```

Also, I will suggest you to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with text only content.

```js
let text = ["Words", "Here"];

var currentItem = 0;
setInterval(() => {

    if (currentItem < text.length) {
        document.getElementById("scrollingText").textContent = text[currentItem];
        currentItem++;
        console.log("Updated to: " + currentItem);
    } else {
        currentItem = 0;
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="scrollingText"></div>
```